# can we monitor any application in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

can we monitor any running application in blackberry i.e.for e.g. if i want to know that if there are 5 running applications and i want to know which application is using camera functionality or Wi-Fi etc.then how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. There is no API available to monitor such parameters you have described.

Comment: Look at the most recent RIM API JavaDoc 7.0: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/index.html and look at classes ApplicationManager and CodeModuleManager. These classes provide functionality to control cod-files and applications on the device. I am not aware about other possibilities.